# Foreach com PHP StdClass

Tags: php, array, laravel, foreach, stdclass

Minha página mostra postagens que foram cadastradas no banco de dados. Algumas postagens possuem arquivos que foram carregados. Esses arquivos são salvos em pastas do servidor e no banco de dados tem a tabela "Arquivos_postagens" com as colunas ID, Postagem, Nome e Tamanho.

```
$postagens = DB::table('postagens')
                ->where('dsa', '=', $id)
                ->OrderBy('Data_publicacao', 'Desc')
                ->get();

foreach ($postagens as $postagem => $post)
{
  $arquivos_postagens[$post['Id_postagem']] = DB::table('arquivos_postagens')
  ->where('postagem','=', $post['Id_postagem'])
  ->first();
}
```

Eu agora estou tentando utilizar o foreach acima para percorrer as postagens e realizar outro select na tabela "Arquivos_postagem" onde a coluna "postagem" receba o valor do id da postagem e armazene o resultado em outro array para que eu o envie para a página e possa trabalhar com cada um deles.

Entretanto, nao está dando certo. Pesquisei e vi alguns vídeos de Array em PHP mas não consegui a informação que precisava. Poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado

Banco:

Tabela Postagens
Campos: ID_Postagem, data_publicacao, descrição, disciplina (dsa), Titulo

Tabela Arquivo_postagens
Campos: ID_arquivo, nome, postagem(ID_postagem), tamanho

Select desejado:

Supondo que o ID_postagem seja igual a 5 quero que retorne uma tabela assim:

ID_Arquivo   Nome         Postagem  Tamanho 
3            leiame.txt   5         1024
4            foto.jpg     5         6780
5            aula.pdf     5         12304

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta os duas tabelas e campos de relação e que vão ser mostrado no select... Qual é a versão do seu Laravel?

Comment: Meu laravel é o 5.3. Irei realizar as edições na pergunta colocando o que você solicitou.

Comment: O relacionamento é 1 `postagem` tem vários `Arquivo_postagens`?

Comment: Isso virgilio. Uma postagem pode ter 0 ou vários arquivos...

Comment: fiz uma resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Eu não sei se sua classe `DB` lhe permite a execução de consultas query, mas, você poderia tentar [JOINs](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/trabalhando-com-join/).

um exemplo prático para esta sua consulta seria:

```
SELECT p.*, ap.dado1, ap.dado2, ap.dado3 FROM postagens p
JOIN Arquivos_postagem ap
ON p.dsa = ap.postagem
WHERE dsa = {$id}
ORDER BY Data_publicacao DESC
```

Onde nas linhas 2 e 3 eu faço a junção de outra tabela para puxar os dados dela e na linha 1 eu especifico entre `SELECT` e `FROM` quais dados eu quero de cada tabela.
Dê uma lida [aqui](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/trabalhando-com-join/) para conhecer mais sobre as JOINs.

Comment: Ajudou, verificarei se em futuros métodos eu consigo aplicar esse conceito. Eu pensei em fazer desse jeito de inicio. Mas nesse caso que apresentei não daria certo pois a minha tabela "arquivos_postagens" não tem a coluna do "DSA" (q é o ID da disciplina que tem as postagens). Só tem a coluna "postagem" q aponta para o Id_postagem na tabela "postagens" que já tem o ID da disciplina rs

Comment: Por favor, não coloque ["Espero ter ajudado"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5458/o-que-fazer-com-o-espero-ter-ajudado-no-final-das-respostas) no final das suas respostas. Acompanhe a discussão no Meta. Isso é um texto considerado irrelevante para o site.

Answer (score 0):

Se a relação for [**1** para **muitos**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) poderia ser feito [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), que vai facilitar o carregamento dos seus [relacionamentos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

**Postagens**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Postagens extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_Postagem';
    protected $fillable = array('data_publicacao',
                                'descricao',
                                'dsa',
                                'titulo');
    protected $table = 'Postagens';
    public $timestamps = false;
    // aqui seria a relação de 1 para muitos...
    public function arquivos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArquivoPostagens::class, 'postagem','ID_Postagem');
    }

}
```

**ArquivoPostagens**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ArquivoPostagens extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_arquivo';
    protected $fillable = array('nome',
                                'postagem',
                                'tamanho');
    protected $table = 'Arquivo_postagens';
    public $timestamps = false;
    // relação onde 1 ArquivoPostagens é de uma postagem
    public function postagem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Postagens::class, 'postagem','ID_Postagem');
    }

}
```

**Como usar:**

Para carregar o [relacionamento](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) utilize o comando `with`, para que no momento da criação seja também carregado a relação:

```
$postagens = Postagens::with(['arquivos'])
                      ->where('dsa', '=', $id)
                      ->orderBy('Data_publicacao', 'Desc')
                      ->get();
```

Dentro da variável `$postagens` se existir a relação ele vai ter um item `arquivos` com a relação dos arquivos para aquela determinada `$postagens`. Dessa forma não precisa se preocupar em buscar separadamente os arquivos, o próprio [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) tem a função para trazer os dados conforme a relação. Não vejo motivos então para usar `DB::` nesse caso pelo fato de desempenho que para cada item da postagem é feito um `Select`, isso pode causar uma certa lentidão no processo de carregamento.

***Referencias:***

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
- [Defining Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)
- [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)
- [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Uma pergunta Virgilio: Em que pasta devo colocar o arquivo desses Models no Laravel?

Comment: Particularmente eu crio dentro da pasta `app` um pasta `Models` (`app\Models`), e o `namespace App\Models` (como está no exemplo do código). Isso é um padrão que tinha e eles removeram, pra mim nunca deveria ter saído. A criação normal é espalhado (bem isso mesmo) na pasta `app`.